# Formatting using BufWritePost ends up with WARNING

Tags: autocmd, external-command, functions, command, filetype-php

I am trying to format PHP files using the following function:

```
function! PHPCSFixer()                                                                                   
    let l:fixer_path = '$HOME/.devtools/php/php-cs-fixer-v2.phar'               
    let l:config_path = '$HOME/.devtools/php/php-cs-fixer.conf'                 
    let l:cmd = l:fixer_path . ' fix --quiet --config="' . l:config_path . '" -- "' . expand('%:p') . '"'
                                                                                
    :call system(l:cmd)                                                         
    :edit!                                                                      
endfun                                                                          
command! PHPCSFixer call PHPCSFixer()                                           
autocmd BufWritePost *.php silent :PHPCSFixer
```

It just run the following script on the current file (https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer).

The problem is that every once in a while when I save (:w) a PHP file a warning pops up:

```
WARNING: The file has been changed since reading it!!!
Do you really want to write to it (y/n)?
```

I guess there is a timing problem somewhere but I don't know how/what to do to fix it...

Can someone point me to the right direction on this issue?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You may want to investigate whether or not that script can run as a filter of stdin to stdout—it would avoid this problem altogethee

Comment: Hmm I don't understand what you mean by that, can you explain that a little more? Thanks!

Comment: cat, sort, awk, sed, grep, these are all commands that take input, filter it (or not, in the case of cat), and produce output. This makes it very easy to filter a buffer through the command without needing to `:edit!` afterwards. Can your formatter take the code to format as standard input and produce the result on standard output, or does it only work by modifying files in-place?

Comment: OK, I get your point now. The fixer does take input from `stdin` but it does not output the result to `stdout` :| There is issues opened on the git repo of the fixer but they don't seem to plan that... The `stdin` input is pretty useless as far as I can tell. I guess I can write to a tmp file, fix it, cat to the buffer :/

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following solution:

```
" make a tmp file & write buffer content to it
let l:tmp = system('mktemp')
execute 'write! ' . l:tmp

" fix the tmp file
let l:cmd = l:fixer_path . ' fix --quiet --config="' . l:config_path . '" -- "' . l:tmp . '"'
call system(l:cmd)

" cat tmp file to buffer & keep cursor pos
let l:save_cursor = getpos('.')
execute '%!cat ' . l:tmp
call setpos('.', l:save_cursor)

execute '!rm ' . l:tmp
```

Not very elegant I guess but working